# Cassandra DataStax Community Edition Add Node to Cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I've installed the DataStax Community Edition of Cassandra on a Microsoft Windows 2008 R2 server. Running in a single-node cluster is no problem. The problem is when I try to add a second node to the cluster. After making what I believe are the appropriate changes to the cassandra.yaml file, I can no longer start the DataStax Cassandra Community Server 2.0.2 service. The error is "The Datastax Cassandra Community Server 2.0.2 service on local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs." And the application log indicates a problem with the prunsrv.exe file.

Here's the relevant cassandra.yaml file for Node1:

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster' 
num_tokens: 256 
# initial_token: 
seed_provider: 
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider 
parameters: 
- seeds: "X.X.X.221, X.X.X.222" 
listen_address: X.X.X.221  
rpc_address: X.X.X.221  
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
```

Here's the relevant cassandra.yaml file for Node2:

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster' 
num_tokens: 256 
# initial_token: 
seed_provider: 
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider 
parameters: 
- seeds: "X.X.X.221, X.X.X.222" 
listen_address: X.X.X.222  
rpc_address: X.X.X.222  
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch
```

On both nodes, I've set up inbound firewall rule to open ports 7000, 7001, 9160, 7199, 9042, 8888, 50031, 61620, 8012, 9290, 50030, 50060, 61621, 22, and 8983.

I'm new to Cassandra, so I assume I'm missing something obvious. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue on both physical servers? Or just one of them?

Comment: Yes. Both servers have the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no quotes around the values for `seeds`:

```
seed_provider:
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
  parameters:
  - seeds: X.X.X.221, X.X.X.222
```

*Note*: make sure you have the indentation right in (yaml files are strict about their format)

Comment: You are right. By looking at another untouched cassandra.yaml file, I was able to tweak my cassandra.yaml files on each node and get the Cassandra  Server Services to startup. In particular, I was using tabs for indentation, which is a big no-no in yaml.

Comment: But now with the services started up on each node, I get 0 active nodes in OpsCenter and an error ("Error loading cluster view: Unknown cluster partitioner") when clicking on ring view. Any ideas here?

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out. Within OpsCenter, I had to go to "Edit Cluster.." and also add the 2 IP addresses. After doing that, I see two nodes in the ring and the name of the cluster is listed in OpsCenter. Thanks Alex.